# List Project specific Regions for Google Cloud via API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-python

Is there any Google Cloud API which can be used to fetch project specific regions, instead of getting all regions where Google Cloud operates?

Currently, when I try to list using `v1/projects/{project}/regions/list` ([Regions List API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regions/list)), it always returns all the regions where Google Cloud operates.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `project specific regions`? All regions are available to a project. If you review VPCs, you will find that a VPC spans all regions. Google Cloud does not have the concept that you must enable a region to use it.

Comment: I share the doubts of the previous comment. All regions are available to a project. Do you intend to get a list of the regions that your project is using?

Comment: Let me clarify. I am looking for all regions where resources are provisioned and consumed for a specific project vs all regions applicable for Google Cloud.

Generally, Cloud Users do not use services from all regions. But, use specific regions. I am looking for an api which can return all the regions where the Cloud user has provisioned resources.

Comment: Consider Cloud Asset Inventory https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview

Comment: @JohnHanley Cloud Asset Inventory does not seem to have any APIs for regions utilized by a specific project :(

Comment: Have you tried executing something like this?: "gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope projects/<PROJECT_NAME> | grep zone" . At least in my case, I only obtain the regions used by my project.